# BRDF and Point Light - Abrupt Shadows

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm following [this BRDF implementation](https://github.com/wdas/brdf/blob/main/src/brdfs/disney.brdf)
which returns 0 when `(NdotL < 0 || NdotV < 0)`, i.e., when the normal is pointing away from the light source.

This results in very abrupt shadows, as can be seen in the attached figure, which shows `NdotL` on the left, and the computed BRDF on the right.

Is this to be expected and what are possible mitigation approaches? Just add more light sources?

[image: NdotL and diffuse BRDF result]